# I keep getting the same problem: JNI error has occurred

Tags: java

I keep getting the same problem on my pc (win10) when trying to compile and run a java programme:

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: euler1 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I have installed the following:
javac -version
javac 14.0.1

java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You have a JRE on your path before your new JDK. When you run java it is running java 8. You should either: uninstall that JRE or change the order of your path entries.

Comment: I think they're entries separated by ';'s There should be an entry for your java 8 installation. If it is alphabetical, I think that is a coincidence. Maybe somebody with windows can give you better help. You can also just fix your path in the cmd prompt your in instead of changing things globally.

Comment: the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin" is above the "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin" i nthe path list.

Comment: Where does "1.8.0_261" appear? It might be on the system path some where too. Also did you check this in the cmd prompt your running java from? Sometimes you have to restart the shell to see the changes. I think you can `echo %PATH%`

Comment: I was checking the list in windows not in cmd prompt. Now that I've checked it in the cmd promt it does look like JRE comes before JDK - how do I change this order (changing it globally)? And how do I fix the path in cmd prompt locally each time. I'd like to be able to do both. thx

Comment: I managed to change the order of the JDK and the JRE paths using windows' dialog window, so that now when I echo "PATH" the JDK path is listed before the JRE path. BUT the problem remain. I'm getting the following error message: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: euler1 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Maybe add the descriptions to your question then. ie. `echo %PATH%` `javac -version` and `java -version`. Does windows have the command `which`? Maybe you can include `which java`. Since you've mentioned the jre is 251, but the java -version is 261 you might have *another* jre. Another thing you can do, to see. Use the whole path of the java executable. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java". If that is broken then it might not be you path.